# iOS - Is there a way to detect popular keywords from a user's text input and sort by popularity or trending?

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, text-recognition, keyword-spotting

I am building an app that will allow users to type into a UITextInput field. I want to be able to scan what they type and extract possible keywords/phrases that could be used to populate other things in the app, and also have them sorted by popularity/trending.

Example:

1. The user types the following string into the input: "*My siblings are so
   embarrassing and I can't wait for them to leave me alone!*"
2. Expected Keyword Extraction: "*siblings, embarrassing, alone,...*"
3. Expected Keyword Sorting by Popularity/Trend: "*embarrassing,
   siblings, alone,...*"

Is there an SDK or native iOS solution for this?